# Vectorising a for loop containing a which statement and a function

Tags: r, vectorization

A reproducible example of the code I'm trying vectorise.

```
cutOffs <- seq(1,10,0.2)

plotOutput <- matrix(nrow=length(cutOffs), ncol=2)
colnames(plotOutput) <- c("x","y")
plotOutput[,"y"] <- cutOffs

for(plotPoint in 1:length(cutOffs))
{
  plotOutput[plotPoint, "x"] <-
    nrow(iris[ which(iris$Sepal.Length > cutOffs[plotPoint] &
                   iris$Sepal.Width > cutOffs[plotPoint]), ])
}

plotOutput
```

Specifically what I'm looking to find out is, if there's a way to vectorise this part.

```
nrow(iris[ which(iris$Sepal.Length > cutOffs[plotPoint] &
                   iris$Sepal.Width > cutOffs[plotPoint]), ])
```

Let's say I was to use the plyr library or some form of apply, there's probably not much speed up, which is really what I'm looking for. Fundamentally I'm trying to see if there's some technique for vectorising that I've overlooked or managed to miss while searching.

UPDATE:

```
Unit: milliseconds
  expr         min          lq        mean      median          uq         max neval
  op() 33663.39700 33663.39700 33663.39700 33663.39700 33663.39700 33663.39700     1
  jr()  3976.53088  3976.53088  3976.53088  3976.53088  3976.53088  3976.53088     1
  dd()  4253.21050  4253.21050  4253.21050  4253.21050  4253.21050  4253.21050     1
 exp()  5085.45331  5085.45331  5085.45331  5085.45331  5085.45331  5085.45331     1
 nic()  8719.82043  8719.82043  8719.82043  8719.82043  8719.82043  8719.82043     1
  sg()    16.66177    16.66177    16.66177    16.66177    16.66177    16.66177     1
```

A more realistic approximation of what I'm actually doing is this

```
# generate data
numObs <- 1e5
iris <- data.frame( Sepal.Length = sample(1:numObs), Sepal.Width = sample(1:numObs) )

cutOffs <- 1:(numObs*0.01)

plotOutput <- matrix(nrow=length(cutOffs), ncol=2)
colnames(plotOutput) <- c("x","y")
plotOutput[,"y"] <- cutOffs
```

followed by whichever particular method one prefers.

Generally speaking it'll be used on data sets with 50,000 - 200,000 points.

There was a big jump from using

```
sum(Sepal.Length > cutOffs[plotPoint] & Sepal.Width > cutOffs[plotPoint])
```

which is what I was missing as a more optimal approach in the first place.

By far however, the best answer is sgibb's sg(). The key is realising it's only lowest of the two values in each row that matters. Once that mental leap has been made there's only a single vector left to deal with and vectorising is reasonably straightforward.

```
# cutOff should be lower than the lowest of Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width
  m <- pmin(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I like to add another answer:

```
sg <- function() {
  # cutOff should be lower than the lowest of Sepal.Length & Sepal.Width
  m <- pmin(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width)
  ms <- sort.int(m)
  # use `findInterval` to find all the indices 
  # (equal to "how many numbers below") lower than the threshold
  plotOutput[,"x"] <- length(ms)-findInterval(cutOffs, ms)
  plotOutput
}
```

This approach avoids a `for` or `outer` loop and is 4x times faster than @nicola's approach:

```
microbenchmark(sg(), nic(), dd())
#Unit: microseconds
#  expr     min       lq     mean   median       uq      max neval
#  sg()  88.726 104.5805 127.3172 123.2895 144.2690  232.441   100
# nic() 474.315 526.7780 625.0021 602.3685 706.7530  997.412   100
#  dd() 669.841 736.7800 887.4873 847.7730 976.6445 2800.930   100

identical(sg(), dd())
# [1] TRUE
```

Comment: Nice indeed with `findInterval` (+1). That was my starting point as well, but I failed miserably and ended up with a much more convoluted `cut` code.

Answer (score 6):

You can use `outer`:

```
plotOutput[,"x"]<-colSums(outer(1:nrow(iris),1:length(cutOffs),function(x,y) iris$Sepal.Length[x] > cutOffs[y] & iris$Sepal.Width[x] > cutOffs[y]))
```

Answer (score 5):

This doesn't remove the `for` loop, but I assume it will give you some speedup - feel free to benchmark and let us know how it compares on your real data:

```
for(i in seq_along(cutOffs)) {
  x <- cutOffs[i]
  plotOutput[i, "x"] <- with(iris, sum(Sepal.Length > x & Sepal.Width > x))
}
```

---

Here's a little benchmark using the sample data (which is arguably tiny, but might give some indication):

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(op(), jr(), dd(), exp(), nic())
Unit: microseconds
  expr      min        lq    median        uq       max neval
  op() 6745.428 7079.8185 7378.9330 9188.0175 11936.173   100
  jr() 1335.931 1405.2030 1466.9180 1728.6595  4692.748   100
  dd()  684.786  711.6005  758.7395  923.6670  4473.725   100
 exp() 1928.083 2066.0395 2165.6985 2392.7030  5392.475   100
 nic()  383.007  402.5495  439.3835  541.6395   851.488   100
```

The functions used in the benchmark are defined as follows:

```
op <- function(){
  for(plotPoint in 1:length(cutOffs))
  {
    plotOutput[plotPoint, "x"] <-
      nrow(iris[ which(iris$Sepal.Length > cutOffs[plotPoint] &
                         iris$Sepal.Width > cutOffs[plotPoint]), ])
  }
  plotOutput
}

jr <- function() {
  cbind(x = sapply(cutOffs, counts), y = plotOutput[,"y"])
}

dd <- function() {
  for(i in seq_along(cutOffs)) {
    x <- cutOffs[i]
    plotOutput[i, "x"] <- with(iris, sum(Sepal.Length > x & Sepal.Width > x))
  }
  plotOutput
}

exp <- function() {
  data_frame(y=cutOffs) %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(x = sum(iris$Sepal.Length > y & iris$Sepal.Width > y))
}

nic <- function() {
  plotOutput[,"x"]<-colSums(outer(1:nrow(iris),1:length(cutOffs),function(x,y) iris$Sepal.Length[x] > cutOffs[y] & iris$Sepal.Width[x] > cutOffs[y]))
}
```

Edit note: included approach by @nicola which is now fastest

Comment: Though I like the smart solution by @nicola, I prefer `dd` because `outer` is memory intensive for very long `cutOffs`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
data_frame(y=cutOffs) %>% 
    rowwise() %>% 
    mutate(x = sum(iris$Sepal.Length > y & iris$Sepal.Width > y))
```

Answer (score 2):

I guess something like:

```
counts <- function(x) sum(iris$Sepal.Length > x & iris$Sepal.Width > x ) 
cbind(x = sapply(cutOffs, counts), y = plotOutput[,"y"])
```

and just to check:

```
res <- cbind(x=sapply(cutOffs,counts), y=plotOutput[,"y"])
identical(plotOutput,res)
[1] TRUE
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possibility based on `pmin`, `cut` and `table`

```
brk <- c(cutOffs, Inf)
rev(cumsum(rev(table(cut(pmin(iris$Sepal.Length, iris$Sepal.Width), brk)))))
```

A smaller example which might be easier to use if you want to work through the code 'from inside out':

```
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x = sample(1:10, 6), y = sample(1:10, 6))
cutOffs <- seq(from = 2, to = 8, by = 2)
brk <- c(cutOffs, Inf)

rev(cumsum(rev(table(cut(pmin(df$x, df$y), brk)))))
#  (2,4]   (4,6]   (6,8] (8,Inf] 
#      4       2       1       0
```

I.e., four rows with both values > 2, two rows with both values > 4, et.c